# Blaze compatibility with Jboss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jboss6.x, blaze-advisor

I am new to blaze advisor. I am not able find any tutorials related to blaze in net. Is blaze advisor or rule processor compatible with Jboss eap 6.2 server? I am looking for sample java application or tutorial to check blaze compatibility in Jboss eap 6.2 server.

Answer (score 0):

Blaze Advisor is compatible with the following JBoss versions (official documentation):

Blaze Advisor **7.2**:

[image]

[image]

Blaze Advisor **7.3**:

[image]

[image]